# Dynamically change page title in CoreUI's CBreadcrumbRouter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, core-ui

I'm working on a VueJS project using the CoreUI admin template.

Is there a way to modify the title of the current page, as it is displayed on the CBreadcrumbRouter? According to the GitHub, the script seems to prefer to display meta.label followed by the name property of the router. However, I haven't found an option or instruction on how to change the display from the content page. I would like to display a different text here using the call parameter. I already tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
this.$route.meta.label = 'bla';
```

Instead of `path / to / my / page`, it should display `path / to / my / {script defined page name}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually set the meta label property from the page, if you don't define it on the router. If you set it on the router, it doesn't update. So in `configRoutes()`, don't set the meta tag! Otherwise it won't update.

Answer (score 1):

Meta is a read-only property, and can be assigned on router instance (it is property of path object)

```
meta: { label: 'custom-label' },
```

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-construction-options